# regex - "Search until it doesnt match ;\d+\;\d+\.\d+;\W\d+\.\d+ but exclude anything before"

Tags: regex, notepad++

I use this Syntax to find Errors in Notepad++ Handwritten Textfiles

`;\d+\;\d+\.\d+;\W\d+\.\d+`

The base Form is `(names with and without numbers);id;d(2).d(6);-d(2).d(6)`

For an Example:

`name;1;11.222222;-11.222222` Correct

`name;111.222222;-11.222222`  Incorrect

`name;;11.222222;-11.222222`  Incorrect

It's quite inefficient to search through 200 of those lines to find one Error. But how do I highlight only the Errors in those files?

I tried with `[^;\d+\;\d+\.\d+;\W\d+\.\d+]`but it single matched every character and whitespace. Also im not sure how to ignore the beginning name since it can be a name with or without numbers and I tried to help myself with the [Rexegg Cheatsheet](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html).

Comment: This should match what you want : `[a-zA-Z0-9]+;\d;\d{2}\.\d{6};-\d{2}\.\d{6}`

Comment: Use `^(?!.*;\d+;\d{2}\.\d{6};-\d{2}\.\d{6}).*`

Comment: Hey thanks Seblor for the fast answer I only added `[a-zA-Z0-9]+;\d+;\d{2}\.\d{6};-\d{2}\.\d{6}` so the id can have more than 0-9 should have mentioned that. But with this it only shows the correct Lines and not the false one. If I want to highlight only the Errors now it should look smth like this? `[a-zA-Z0-9]+[^(;\d+;\d{2}\.\d{6};-\d{2}\.\d{6})]` But with that it highlights the `name` and the last `\d{6}`.Sorry if I didnt explained it correctly English isnt my first Language.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor thats exactly what i looked for.